# Wordpress MySQL result resource is not valid

Tags: mysql, wordpress, while-loop

I have **wp_places** custom table and I am getting this when I am printing array:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [home_location] => 24
        )

[1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [home_location] => 29
        )
```

Now I want to implode value like this way (24,29) but in my code I am getting this error:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

**My Code**

```
$getGroupType = $_POST['parent_category'];
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT home_location FROM wp_places WHERE blood_group LIKE '".$getGroupType."%'" );


    $bgroup = Array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $bgroup[] =  implode(',',$row);
    }
    echo implode(',',$bgroup);
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$wpdb->get_results()` already do the fetching for you, you don't need to call `mysql_fetch_array`

Given what you want to do, your code should look like this :

```
$getGroupType = $_POST['parent_category'];
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT home_location FROM wp_places WHERE blood_group LIKE '".$getGroupType."%'" );


$bgroup = Array();
foreach ($result as $location) {
    $bgroup[] =  $location->home_location;
}
echo '('.implode(',',$bgroup).')';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an PHP object that contains results, it isn't a MySQL Result.

Looking at the [**docs**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results), it should be used like

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $bgroup[] = $row->home_location;
}
echo implode(',',$bgroup)
```